# cypress - How can we bypass cross origin policy while automating using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am trying to automate a web application using Cypress. But, unable to load the site as it requires authentication from another source (Iframe). Is there any way to overcome this?

**Sample code:**

```
describe('Initial Cypress Tests', () => {
it('navigate to MSteams site', () => {
    cy.visit('https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/')
} )
```

})

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cypress for automation but to test your web application.

> ***Cypress is not a general purpose automation tool.***

(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Permanent-trade-off).

Each cypress test is limited to a single superdomain. The guys at cypress thought about third-party logins and use cases where you authenticate at a different source. You can use their 'recipes' to authenticate with third parties: https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Single-Sign-On

There are different ways to test your application using cypress, here are some examples:

> - Stub out the OAuth provider and bypass using their UI altogether. You could just trick your application into believing the OAuth provider has passed its token to your application.
> - If you must get a real token you can use `cy.request()` and use the programmatic API that your OAuth provider provides. These APIs likely change more infrequently and you avoid problems like throttling and A/B campaigns.
> - Instead of having your test code bypass OAuth, you could also ask your server for help. Perhaps all an OAuth token does is generate a user in your database. Oftentimes OAuth is only useful initially and your server establishes its own session with the client. If that is the case, just use `cy.request()` to get the session directly from your server and bypass the provider altogether.

(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#When-logging-in)